# Coldfusion gateway, problem with application.cfc OnRequestStart

Tags: coldfusion, gateway, application.cfc

My application.cfc uses the OnRequestStart to check users are logged in

```
<cfif not isDefined("session.auth.isLoggedIn")>
  <cfinclude template="loginForm.cfm">
  <cfabort>
</cfif>
```

and this is mangling my attempts to use a gateway service which errors out with

```
Error invoking CFC for gateway watchInboundFiles: null {GATEWAYTYPE={FileWatcher},ORIGINATORID={},CFCMETHOD={onDelete},DATA={{FILENAME={C:\temp\New Text Document.txt},TYPE={DELETE}}},CFCPATH={F:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\watch_dir.cfc},GATEWAYID={watchInboundFiles}}.
```

If I comment out the OnRequestSTart method the gateway works as expected.

Someone else ran into this before [here](http://cfsilence.com/blog/client/index.cfm/2007/1/26/Warning--CF-Gateways-Invoke-Applicationcfc) and a solution is apparently to

> add a new application.cfc which
>   extended my original but overrode the
>   onRequestStart() - which worked
>   perfectly.

So how do I do that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question:

Your new `Application.cfc` will live **in another directory** but extend your original:

```
<cfcomponent extends="path.to.my.original.Application">

  <cffunction name="onRequestStart">
    <!--- No login code here --->
  </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

All other functions are available as usual.

Hoep that helps! More info [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1179-Ask-Ben-Extending-Application-cfc-And-OnRequestStart-With-SUPER.htm).

Comment: Yeah, thats the info I was looking for thanks. In the end  used the "proxy method Sean Corfield describes here http://corfield.org/entry/Extending_Your_Root_Applicationcfc

Answer (score 2):

You could also add something to the application.cfc to see if the call is coming from the gateway.  If so then skip the if block.

Comment: I spent many hours trying to make a iron-clad determination of a gateway call vs. a webserver-originated call, and was unable to do it to my satisfaction, so I ended up doing the extra application.cfc thing myself.  But, if you want to try, the only things I found as markers were various missing CGI variables.